# Inserting a number into a list in a mongodb subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB of the form:

```
{"_id" : 1, "value" : { "listOfNumbers" : [2,3,4]}}
```

I can't seem to figure out, how to insert a new number into the "listOfNumbers". I found:

```
db.collection.update({_id:1}, {listOfNumbers : 8})
```

This only works if the above document would be of the form (a document without a sub document):

```
{"_id" : 1, "listOfNumbers" : [2,3,4]}
```

I tried playing around with all sorts of combinations, but none worked as expected. 
Would anybody know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following syntax :

```
db.collection.update({_id:1}, {$push:{'value.listOfNumbers' : 8}})
```

It will push the value 8 in your array **listOfNumbers**